# Why is my php file not taking the data and emailing it

Tags: php, html, contact-form

So I my goal is to take the text entry from the user and then have the entry values sent to a email of my choice. Not sure why but when I enter in data it shoots back a error 405. Here is my contact html and my php file I am trying to connect to it:

```html
<!-- Contact Start -->
<div class="container-xxl py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row g-5">
      <div class="col-lg-6 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
        <h1 class="display-6 mb-5">
          If You Have Any Concerns or Would Like to Contact Us Please Do:
        </h1>
        <p class="mb-4">
          Once you submit a message, we will get an email and be back with you shortly!
        </p>
        <form method="post" action="php/saveddata.php">
          <div class="row g-3">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-floating">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="name"
                  name="name"
                  placeholder="Your Name"
                />
                <label for="name">Your Name</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-floating">
                <input
                  type="email"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Your Email"
                />
                <label for="email">Your Email</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-floating">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="subject"
                  name="subject"
                  placeholder="Subject"
                />
                <label for="subject">Subject</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-floating">
                <textarea
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Leave a message here"
                  id="message"
                  name="message"
                  style="height: 100px"
                ></textarea>
                <label for="message">Message</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <button class="btn btn-pink py-3 px-5" type="submit">
                Send Message
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div
        class="col-lg-6 wow fadeIn"
        data-wow-delay="0.5s"
        style="min-height: 450px"
      >
        <div class="position-relative rounded overflow-hidden h-100">
          <!-- New Map Location (Real location of office) -->
          <iframe
            class="position-relative w-100 h-100"
            src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d12135.857595442715!2d-       85.89060334214923!3d38.96079969677196!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x886b4a8dcdc02db3%3A0x46cc5a5c8d8ce21e!2s425%20W%202nd%20St%2C%20Seymour%2C%20IN%2047274%2C%20USA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sbd!4v1603794290143!5m2!1sen!2sbd"
            frameborder="0"
            style="min-height: 450px; border: 0"
            allowfullscreen=""
            aria-hidden="false"
            tabindex="0"
          ></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Contact End -->
```

```php
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  
  // Set the recipient email address
  $to = 'sagegetts2001@gmail.com'; // Replace with your own email address
  
  // Set the email subject
  $email_subject = 'New Contact Form Submission';
  
  // Build the email content
  $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
  $email_content .= "Email: $email\n";
  $email_content .= "Subject: $subject\n";
  $email_content .= "Message: $message\n";
  
  // Set the email headers
  $headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
  
  // Send the email
  if (mail($to, $email_subject, $email_content, $headers)) {
    // Email sent successfully
    echo 'Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly.';
  } else {
    // Failed to send email
    echo 'Oops! An error occurred while sending your message. Please try again.';
  }
} else {
  // Invalid request method
  echo 'Invalid request';
}
?>
```

I tried multiple things like making sure the php file was in the correct directory.. I am coding this all on vs code. Am I missing something like Apache or?? idk please help lol

Comment: PS If thats your real email address I would get another one

Comment: HTTP 405 is Method Not Allowed, so that could be something in your PHP or Apache config not accepting POSTs. But even when you get that working, this is highly unlikely to work on a typical home PC, as pretty much every residential ISP blocks outbound port 25. I would strongly suggest against wheel reinvention here and go with a package that does this, or a separate mail provider altogether.

Comment: My bad, that is not my email address I just did not want my email to be public. What do you recommend @DanielTharp for my goals? I just need put in the right track. and I need this contact form to work on any pc and phone for this business, thanks!

Comment: You should look at the [PHPMailer library](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: What do you mean by "to work on any pc". The PHP only executes on the server.

Comment: @DanielTharp Should I restart the code like when I code a HTML contact form that emails me the values, what do I need all implemented into it? I need a Apache config file? I need php file to handle the data I know, What else do I need? Do I need a sql database?

Comment: ___Little Info___ The `mail()` function in PHP does not send email. It only passes an email to the locally configured Mail Server. On Windows you dont have one of these by default so mail will never get sent, however if you use the PHPMailer library, you can quite easily send email using a remote SMTP Server. It also has easy ways to send more than just a simple email, like attachments

Comment: There are a number of ways you could go about this. The simplest solution would be to build a Google Forms page and embed it, and have Google Forms email you when it's submitted. You could set up a Wordpress service with something like Advanced Contact Form and a host that provides mail services. Edited to add: You can use the PHPMailer library as suggested and find a transactional email service like Mailgun to use as a mail relay. You could talk to your ISP and get set up with a static IP and outbound mail capability. That order is probably the preferred order I'd go about it.

Comment: First off thank you guys so much like I have been banging my head onto this. @RiggsFolly I see, so I am calling the wrong function? and can I use this https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer for my goal? that code should be able to help me to take enrty and email it to myself right?

Comment: @DanielTharp I like the idea of google form, that is a very easy method

Comment: Yes phpMailer would assist as it will allow you to send your email via your Gmail account using their SMTP server (SMTP = the part of emailing that does the sending)

Comment: So if I use Php mailer I could make a form and take the entered data and email it to a email? using SMTP

Comment: What PhpMailer buys you is the ability to configure the host that will send the email, which you'd still need to figure out. You can google "transactional email service" for some options there, and many of them will have demo code showing how to use it with PhpMailer.

Comment: Okay thanks @DanielTharp You think I should just go with embedding a google form? that would be the easiest wouldn't it?

Comment: I wouldn't hesitate to do it for a decent number of use cases. I've seen doctor's offices that make use of it. It'll also provide you that database on the backend of it so you don't miss an email, they'll all be in the submitted forms data.

Comment: `I enter in data it shoots back a error 405`...my guess is you're not using a proper webserver to run this